# Fit Gaussian to a custom histogram

Tags: fitting, distributions, uncertainty

I have written a small program that performs a Monte Carlo simulation to calculate the uncertainty of a quantity. I store all the results of this quantity in a list and from this list I generate a histogram.

```
h = 2*(Quantile[listR13A, 3/4] - Quantile[listR13A, 1/4])/nr^(1/3);
Show[Histogram[listR13A, {h}, "Probability"], PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

nr is the number of trials, listR13A is the above list where I store my results.
h is the width of the bins. I wanted my own binning routine so that I know what is happening.
Now  would like to fit a Gaussian function to this histogram and obtain sigma and mu.
How can I do this?

Comment: Use the raw data rather than the censored data placed into histogram bins to estimate the parameters of a normal distribution.

Comment: okay, how do i get them? Sorry, I am a total beginner.
BinLists, right?

Comment: By the raw data I mean the individual values of the quantity you're simulating.  All you need is the sample mean and sample variance to estimate the population mean and population variance.  That can be done by just collecting the sum of the simulated values, the sum of the squares of the individual values, and the total number of simulations.  But if the number of simulations is not large (say less than 10,000,000), then you could keep all of the raw values and calculate the sample statistics at the end.

Comment: okay, BinCounts and BinLists was not the right choice either. So what is it?

Comment: @JimB okay this is also a good approach, I will compare the results, if I mange to get want I like. but thank you!

Comment: "...if I manage to get what I like."  Is there some goodness-of-fit-test that uses that criterion?  That would make my life much simpler.

Comment: ohoo sorry did no t want to sound snippy. I would like to first bin my data set and then fit a Gaussian to it if it is Gaussian-ish.  h like it is given above is just a estimate of the bin width. So my idea was to bin it, plot the histogram and then decide if I want a Gaussian or a other distribution.

Comment: If the assumption is that there is some underlying smooth probability distribution, then you might want to consider using `SmoothHistogram` or `SmoothKernelDistribution`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of fitting a *function* to the histogram (an estimate of the PDF), it is generally better to fit a *distribution* (not a function) to the raw, unbinned data.

Use `FindDistributionParameters` or `EstimatedDistribution`.

---

Example:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200];

EstimatedDistribution[data, NormalDistribution[mean, sigma]]
```

---

You *could* do this, but *DON'T*. It is not reliable (it depends on the binning you use) and it does not give you a proper normalized PDF.

```
{bins, vals} = HistogramList[data, Automatic, "PDF"]

NonlinearModelFit[{MovingAverage[bins, 2], vals}\[Transpose], 
 c*Exp[-b*(x - m)^2], {b, c, m}, x]
```

Comment: So what is the better option now? I did not get it.

Comment: @Zorg I showed two methods, and told you to use one, and not the other. Do you have any specific suggestions for improving the phrasing?

Comment: @Zorg If you're asking about `FindDistributionParameters` vs `EstimatedDistribution`: they do the same thing, they just return the result differently.

Comment: Okay, 'EstimatedDistribution' seems to be the best option for what I want.
But I have encountered a different problem. I want to plot the histogram and the PDF in the same plot, and I like to have the histogram with the "Probability" option, but how can I normalize the PDF?

Comment: D = ProbabilityDistribution[myProbFnc, {u, -1, 1},  Method -> "Normalize"]; Show[                                                
 Histogram[Table[icdf, {i, Range[10^4]}], Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[D[u], {u, -1, 1}]
 ]